# Endless Errors with Xamarin when installing NuGet package

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, package, nuget

I tried to install a NuGet for Splash Screen for Xamarin.Forms but this package broke my working app and it became a loop of errors. One error says:

> Install Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1

when I tried to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 other error says:

> Install Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI 27.0.2.1

but when I tried to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI it says again:

> Install Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1.

I mean what the heck is this? whats wrong with that VS. It's really annoying that I encounter this situation several times. Is there any solution to this endless loop?

Comment: This is due to a limitation in NuGet where it doesn't properly resolve versions.

Just make sure you have Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat and Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs installed first. Install the 28 packages, and then install nuget package.

Comment: What is the Splash Screen NuGet package? It looks like it is failing to install the dependencies for the NuGet hence why it is making you install them manually. e.g. Support Core UI has a dependency on support compat see here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI/27.0.2.1 Can you check the package log when you go to install the splash screen NuGet it may be failing there

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT: Also when I tried to install version 28 of Support.Compat it gaves another error Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations v28 and then when I tried to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations it gaves another error install Support.Compat v28.... it goes like that. Its endless loop.

Comment: @IainSmith: splash screen needs "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" and "Xamarin.Android.Support.v4". I installed v7AppCompat and Support.v4 gave error for nuget compatibility. After that error wave started.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.

Comment: Update the version of XF to latest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried few things but I found the solution with the creating new project and transport all the codes to that new project. It is exhaustive but It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all Xamarin.Android.* packages and install only:

```
 <PackageReference Include=“Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils” Version=“28.0.0.3" />
```